# Entity Framework 6, oracle and sql server together

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, entity-framework-6, transactionscope

We have a requirement to perform Transaction based operation in both SQL Server & Oracle simultaneously, like certain contents of the Single Record has to be added in SQL Server 2008+ and the remaining contents needs to be added in Oracle and if anyone fails then it should roll back the entire transaction.

Can we achieve it somehow using TransactionScope of EntityFramework6.x? or some other means.

Comment: Linked Server from SQL Server to Oracle and Distributed Transaction

Comment: I have had better luck with external transactions such as EF6 and MSMQ and Service Bus than I have had with relying on the Linked  server queries to do this.   I also have had the option to store everything needed in one of the two DB's kind of like a pre transaction table similar to a queue.

Comment: Linked servers are unfortunately not allowed in our professional environment and this approach has its own drawbacks, but can we achieve distributed Transaction-based DML's in both Oracle & SQL server simultaneously?